# How to return the contents of the page loaded by .post, when encased in .when?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, .post, .when

This is the basic framework of my page:

```
$.when(postrequest1, postrequest2).then(function () {
  // how do I access the results of postrequest1 and postrequest 2 here?
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.when(postrequest1, postrequest2).then(function (data1,data2) {
  // data1, data2 are arrays of the form [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] 
});
```

Simply give  data arguments to the anonymous callback function. See [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) for more details.

Comment: yes, but will the `data` variable contain the content from postrequest1 or postrequest2?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.when(postrequest1, postrequest2).then(function (a1,a2) {
 var jqXHR1 = a1[2]; /* arguments are [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] */
  alert(jqXHR1.responseText);

  var jqXHR2 = a2[2]; 
  alert(jqXHR2.responseText); 
});
```

a1 and a1 are arguments for 1st and 2nd ajax request respectively...

a1 and a2 are array each having keys as `(success,statusText,jqXHR)`

you can then handle them individually.

**Documentation** :http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$.when(postrequest1, postrequest2).then(function (postData1, postData2) {

});
```

(As long as the post requests are single requests, otherwise the `then` params can be arrays)